# Using Lambda Expression To Code An Exponent In C++

Tags: c++, lambda

How can I write an "X to the power of k" procedure in C++? (k is a positive integer)

I did the same thing in python, and it was a breeze, but in C++, I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: What does this have to do with lambda? Also, showing your python version may help.

Comment: Doesn't Python have an operator `**` to do that ? Indeed C++ doesn't.

Comment: @Quentin `std::pow()`? :-)

Comment: @melpomene `std::pow` is overkill for integer powers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write an "X to the power of k" procedure in C++? (k is a positive integer)

Write a short loop in a function like

```
int pow(int X, int k) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) result *= X;
    return result;
}
```

It's easy to express this in a lambda as well:

```
auto pow = [] (int X, int k) { 
     int result = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) result *= X;
     return result; 
};

cout << pow(5,3);
```

See a [working sample](http://ideone.com/yLxozY) please.

Answer (score 0):

Ummm, maby try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath> //adds math functions: power, square root etc.

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int x;
  int k;

  cin >> x;
  cin >> k;

 x = pow(x, k);
 cout << "\nX to the power of k: " << x << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::pow()` deals with `float` or `double` values.

Comment: It deals with anything you give to it. Maby it is overkill for integer values but I guess it is a fastest way to solve that kind of a problem.